# Recursive Search for *.MKV Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, automation

I'm mostly a Windows guy and have a fair amount of scripting ability in PowerShell. Although, more recently I've been interested in learning bash due to the popularity of Linux.

Anyhow,
I have a general script already for encoding certain video files based on their extension. Although this is very basic and not robust enough for me to be satisfied. To help me better understand bash, I'd like it if someone could show me code that can do this recursively, regardless of how deep the directories go.

**encode.sh**

```
for INF in "/mnt/usbhdd"/**/**/**/*.mkv
do
  ffmpeg -i "$INF" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 22 -profile:v main -level:v 4.0  -c:a aac -ac 2 -ab 320k "${INF%.*}.m4v"
done
```

As you can see, the first line is not ideal by any means, I run this script with nohup so it can run until complete.

If you can create the code for this to be done recursively (with the possibility of setting the parent folder) and explain any changes, I would really appreciate the help in learning.

Comment: You are interested in the [recursive glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49913/273492). Just enable the bash option with [`shopt -s globstar`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and use `/mnt/usbhdd/**/*.mkv` instead.

Comment: Also search for _If you need recursion_ in this [bash pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: @kvantour The first one is what I was looking for. Thanks for all of the helpful links!

Comment: @kvantour find also does the tick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Kudos to @kvantour for guidance:**

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in /mnt/usbhdd/**/*.mkv; do ls "$f"; done
```

OR

```
find /mnt/usbhdd/ -name '*.mkv'
```

Final solution:

```
shopt -s globstar;
for f in /mnt/usbhdd/**/*.mkv
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 22 -profile:v main -level:v 4.0  -c:a aac -ac 2 -ab 320k "${f%.*}.m4v"
done
```